# MPAndroidChart 2.1 so many things changed

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Until now i used MPAndroidChart 1.7 and everything was great. 
Now i need to use a Combined Chart so i needed to use the new 
version (2.1).

However... so many things changed that i cant resolve all 
the errors now. I used simple things like:

```
chart.setDrawUnitsInChart(false);
chart.setStartAtZero(false);
chart.setDrawYValues(true);
chart.setDrawXLabels(true);
chart.getXLabels().setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
chart.setDrawBorder(false);
chart.setDrawLegend(true);
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false);
```

but these methods all arent existing anymore. And also:

```
data.addLimitLine(limitLine);
```

doenst exist anymore. Where can i find where all this methods were moved to or why they arent supported anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki). You will be able to find most things there.

A lot of the methods you mentioned were previously related to the chart-object itself, and are now "settable" via the `YAxis` (previously YLabels) instances.

Units and custom values can be drawn using the `ValueFormatter` interface.

Some changes:

XLabels -> now XAxis

YLabels -> now YAxis

Enabling disabling axis / legend:

`legend.setEnabled(...)`
`yAxis.setEnabled(...)`

Comment: can you tell me where you move the function to disable to draw the values inside the chart data? i just want the lines to be shown but not the values.

Comment: `dataSet.setDrawValues(false)`